# FFMPEG convert .avi into playable iOS movie mp4

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to convert an avi file which is h264 encoded baseline4.0 to a new h264 mpeg file that is encoded with baseline3.

The file original file is not playable on any iOS device, due to baseline4.0 (I think?)

I'm using this wrapper class here https://github.com/OpenWatch/FFmpegWrapper

but actually I have no clue how to set baseline. I can convert to mpeg4, but it seems that defaults everytime to baseline4.0.

I tried to set it on the AVCodecContext

```
AVCodecContext *outputCodecContext = outputStream->codec;
outputCodecContext->level = 31;
outputCodecContext->profile = FF_PROFILE_H264_BASELINE;
```

but this has no effect.

Perhaps anybody has a clue, or has a better FFMPEGWrapper.

**Specs from original video:**
[image: original video]

Comment: Did you resolve your problem? I have similar one.

Answer (score 2):

First of all take a look at [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008332-CH102-SW8) site to understand which apple devices support what:

> - Encode video using H.264 compression
>
>   - H.264 Baseline 3.0: All devices
>   - H.264 Baseline 3.1: iPhone 3G and later, and iPod touch 2nd generation and later.
>   - H.264 Main profile 3.1: iPad (all versions), Apple TV 2 and later, and iPhone 4 and later.
>   - H.264 Main Profile 4.0: Apple TV 3 and later, iPad 2 and later, and iPhone 4S and later.
>   - H.264 High Profile 4.0: Apple TV 3 and later, iPad 2 and later, and iPhone 4S and later.
>   - H.264 High Profile 4.1: iPad 2 and later and iPhone 4S and later.

The numbers at the end of each profile is not the version of the profile! Its a **Level**. This means if you want to support all devices, you should stick to the Baseline profile and Level 3.0.

I don't know about this wrapper stuff, but using simple ffmpeg you would use this options:

```
-profile:v baseline -level 3.0
```

**Edit**:

I'm sorry, I didn't notice that you already set the level (probably in a right way). But here is one more hint. Notice the call to `av_register_all()` and `avcodec_register_all()` in the `init` of [FFmpegWrapper](https://github.com/OpenWatch/FFmpegWrapper/blob/d640203805aa83050c99eaea9b73cf49201b3065/FFmpegWrapper/FFmpegWrapper.m). Can it be that you first initialize the wrapper and then change the `AVCodecContext`?

Comment: Yes this wrapper has not really a option list, like using the command line. So i need to set the values directly to AVCodec/CodecContext as you mentioned. Yes I initialize the wrapper and then I'm changing the AVCodecContext, how should I change that?

Comment: is it possible to create a wrapper object first, then set the codec context and afterwards to initialize it?

Comment: No I need the Wrapper Object, as there are all values and functions which are triggering the whole libav stuff. I checked, that my changes to the AVCodecContext are made to the Outputfile, when transcoding starts, the correct values are set in AVCodecContext, but ffmpeg doesnt use it. Perhaps I have to set it directly via libav.

Comment: @JulienKlindt try to call `init` again after setting the level